# Centering text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a website as a portfolio for my other work. However I'm having a lot of trouble with centering text within my links. I've tried multiple methods to no avail.

The text I'm trying to alter is the text in the navigation section "about me" "portfolio" "skills" "contact" The text is within a row-->column-->link

I've attempted applying the `text-center` class in multiple different positions throughout the code and I've also tried applying it within my CSS using the `text-align` function. There isn't too much code so I imagine that someone with a bit of HTML experience will solve this in no time.

```css
#mainContainer{
    z-index:0;position:fixed; 
    width:100%; height:100%; 
    background-color: white;
}
.headerClass{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
#headText{
    color:white;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: fantasy;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#infoBox{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#infoBoxCol{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.navbar{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    color:white;
    font-family:fantasy;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    text-align:center;
}
.navRoof{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid  text-center" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: black; height:30%;">
        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-fluid" class="headerClass" id="headText">
            Software Developer
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-2 my-auto"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/logo.jpg" style="max-width:85%;"></div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4 my-auto">
            <div class="row" id="navigation">
                <div class="col-3"><a href="Index.php" class=" navbar text-center">About Me</a></div>
                <div class="col-3"><a href="Index.php" class="navbar text-center">Portfolio</a></div>
                <div class="col-3"><a href="Index.php"  class="navbar text-center">Skills</a></div>
                <div class="col-3"><a href="Index.php" class="navbar text-center">Contact</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that your problem is `padding`, take a look in the `divs`to set an appropriate padding... furthermore, for me, it seems correct when seeing on a bigger screen

Comment: Right okay thanks. So how would you define "appropriate padding"?

Comment: you can use `#navigation div{padding: 4px}` for example... but I would approach in a different way, using `inline-flex` and removing that `col-3` class... but for this I would suggest to read about css flex

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I'll have a look into it!

Comment: I've solved it but I don't understand why this has worked. I've replaced the .navbar with a #navbar and given it the information from the #headText CSS. If Anyone knows why this has fixed it I would very much like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Here i using [bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) instead of row > col-* to have a more flexible design, one thing that you are doing wrong is u are overwriting the bootstrap class "navbar" it have his properties more your news properties this make your design problems. Also is bad idea use vw as unit for font-size if u want get responsive design.

```css
#mainContainer{
    z-index:0;position:fixed; 
    width:100%; height:100%; 
    background-color: white;
}
.headerClass{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
#headText{
    color:white;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: fantasy;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#infoBox{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#infoBoxCol{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.navRoof{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:white;
}
.custom-navbar-container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;   
}
.custom-link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color:white;
  font-family:fantasy;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding: .25rem;
  display: block;    
}
.custom-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid  text-center" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: black; height:30%;">
        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-fluid" class="headerClass" id="headText">
            Software Developer
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-2 my-auto"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/logo.jpg" style="max-width:85%;"></div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4 my-auto">
            <div class="d-flex" id="navigation">
                <div class="p-1">
                  <div class="custom-navbar-container">  
                    <a href="Index.php" class="custom-link">About Me</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-1">
                  <div class="custom-navbar-container">  
                    <a href="Index.php" class="custom-link">Portfolio</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-1">
                  <div class="custom-navbar-container">  
                    <a href="Index.php" class="custom-link">Skills</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-1">
                  <div class="custom-navbar-container">  
                    <a href="Index.php" class="custom-link">Contact</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```